# Cardinality of the set of all circles in $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

A circle is defined to be the set of all points whose distance from the center of the circle is $\le$ r, where r is a positive real number. Let B be the set of all circles in the plane, find the cardinality of B.

My proof shows that the cardinality of $\left|B\right| = \aleph$:
Each circle can be represented as a 3-tuple $\left<x,y,r\right>\in\left< \Bbb R\times\Bbb R \times\left(0,\infty\right) \right>$ therefore there is one-on-one match between each element of B and a 3-tuple as described earlier, in other words there is a bijection. therefore $B$ is equipotent with $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R \times\left(0,\infty\right)$.

$\left|B\right|=\left| \Bbb R\times\Bbb R \times\left(0,\infty\right) \right|=\aleph\cdot\aleph\cdot\aleph=\aleph$

Thus the cardinality of B is the cardinality of the continuum.

Is my proof valid? And did I make any assumptions that I shouldn't have made?

It also seems to me that it could be proved directly that B is equipotent with $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ but I couldn't prove it. My way of thinking was as follows: One can think of a circle as a subset of the plane $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ and B an infinite union of all of these subsets (couldn't continue from here)

Comment: This proof is broadly correct, except that (1) we usually denote the cardinality of the continuum as $\mathfrak c$ and (2) your proof assumes the knowledge of $\mathfrak c^3=\mathfrak c$ (which is, of course true, but depending on the context you may or may not be allowed to use it). For the second attempt, I guess it is misguided as the cardinality of all the subsets of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ is $2^\mathfrak{c}>\mathfrak c$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop (1) in my course we denote it as $\aleph$ that's why I used it here, I guess it doesn't matter. (2) Yeah I actually cut it here to make my question shorter but in my formal proof I wrote the reference to that proof. About the second attempt I still think that a circle is a subset of the plane but maybe B is not a Union of all of these subsets

Comment: The circle is a subset of a plane, but there are too many subsets of the plane (most of them not circles!) - more than  ... ahm ... $\aleph$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop But wouldn't it be possible to take all possible circles and construct cover the plane with them? Overlapping included

Comment: Each point in $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ would be covered by $\aleph$ many of those circles. Thinking about that, this *could* prove what you want (or at least establish the upper bound), because the total number of circles would then be at most $\aleph\cdot\aleph$ (i.e. number of points $\times$ number of circles covering each point). However, proving that each point is covered by $\aleph$ circles isn't any easier than your original proof, and as I said it will only give you the upper bound... Altogether, not impossible, but it seems quite contrived to me.